# In Activity Monitor, how can Swap Used be more than Page Outs?

Tags: virtual-memory

I am trying to understand the relationship between Page Outs and Swap Used as displayed in Activity Monitor.  Currently, Activity Monitor shows:

Page outs:  1.6 MB
Swap used:  8.1 MB

How can there be more swap used than the amount paged out?

Comment: Does not directly address your question (only explains why page out can be much higher than swap), but the two numbers are not comparable, Swap is a snapshot (the current amount), Page outs is cumulative (page the same page out five times and it gets counted five times)

Comment: [How can virtual memory be greater than the total available space?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/16415/8546) (2011-06-24)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is this:

- Program needs access to some data.  Attempts to do so, and fails, due to lack of RAM.
- OS takes control.  There is a page-out operation, where physical RAM is copied to swap.
- There is a page-in operation, where the required data is copied to RAM.
- OS gives control back to program.
- Program tries again, finds its data.

OS's are getting smart about how they choose what and when to to page in/out.  So the operation counts may not be the same, and the swap space may perhaps be in use without there being page outs.

Unless of course I'm backwards on what a page-in/page-out operation is.  In which case your question makes perfect sense.